# How to check existing user account is under administrator group or not?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I'm using a wix installer to install a windows service using an existing user account(logon user account for the window service). I have a customUI dialog which will get the username and password, once the credentials are given while clicking the next button the installer should validate whether the given user is part of builtin administrator group. Should i use custom action or is there anyother way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be a custom action. [WiXUtilExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_index.htm) gives you an option to add new or existing users to the groups (see [User](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_user.htm)/[Group](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_group.htm)/[GroupRef](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_groupref.htm) elements), but this is probably not what you want - it can be quite dangerous.

BTW, you can take advantage of [MSI Extensions project](https://github.com/dblock/msiext) - take a look at [this](http://dblock.github.com/msiext/docs/1.3/_check_membership_8h.html#a5f1f584a1700dc5f7c2c2f51688a2101), it seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you this what i exactly looking for. I think i need a reference of UserPrivileges.dll. Not sure where i can get this one.

Comment: Just download that project - it's all in there, I suppose

Comment: I referred the dll in my custom action. But installer is throwing the error. Failed to Error 2896: Executing action CheckMembership failed.

@yanSklyarenko

Comment: Generate the verbose log file (`/l*v install.log`) and search for the `value 3` in that log. The error explanation will be somewhere close to that message

Comment: This is the error msg got after the executing the custom action:
MSI (c) (84!38) [10:50:40:342]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CA_ERROR property. Its value is '0x80070005 - CheckTokenMembership failed: Access is denied.'.
Action ended 10:50:40: CheckMembership. Return value 3.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the impersonation. In that article I referenced in my answer there's a link at the very bottom, [about impersonation in custom actions](http://dblock.github.com/msiext/docs/1.3/impersonate.html). Take a look at this - unfortunately, I didn't do this myself to give you a sample...

Comment: I tried with the Impersonate option. I can able to validate the user with the built in administrator account. But in order to install/start the service i have to assign the privileges to that user.